# OpenCV 3.0 Windows binary installation with contrib

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

The OpenCV 3.0 binary package for Windows doesn't include the contrib binaries. For instance, if you try to run the python sample called `find_obj.py` it fails with the exception below:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'
```

Is there any place to download the contrib binaries without compiling the entire OpenCV ? What's the purpose of having OpenCV binaries and not the contrib binaries available ?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28323252/1658810 Sorry to say but looks like you will have to build them yourself.

Comment: _What's the purpose of having OpenCV binaries and not the contrib binaries available ?_  OpenCV's extra modules: This repository is intended for development of so-called "extra" modules, contributed functionality. New modules quite often do not have stable API, and they are not well-tested. Thus, they shouldn't be released as a part of official OpenCV distribution, since the library maintains binary compatibility, and tries to provide decent performance and stability.

Comment: Also its not hard to build yourself, and you often times can optimize the build for your specific system to help speed it up. I haven't done any formal testing, but have noticed roughly a 5-10% increase in speed by building it myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [contrib module missing in opencv 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323077/contrib-module-missing-in-opencv-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I searched everywhere and it seems that the binary for the contrib module isn't provided and you have to compile it by yourself.